# How to create menu and it's controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, menu, admin-controller

I want to add my custom menu in admin and also want to add related controller for that.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

In Magento 2 you need to create menu.xml file in your module's `etc/adminhtml` folder.  Here is example of menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::storelocator" title="Lapisbard" module="Lapisbard_StoreLocator" sortOrder="90" resource="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::storelocator" />
        <add id="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::locations" title="Store Locations" module="Lapisbard_StoreLocator" sortOrder="10" parent="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::storelocator" action="lapisbard_storelocator/locations" resource="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::locations"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

`id` should be unique, resource will be used in your acl and using `parent` you will specify in which menu/sub-menu your custom menu should appear. `action="lapisbard_storelocator/locations"` specifies where it will be re-directed.

Example of `acl.xml` which will be present in `etc` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                    <resource id="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::storelocator" title="Lapisbard" sortOrder="10" >
                        <resource id="Lapisbard_StoreLocator::locations" title="Store Locations" sortOrder="40">
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

In `etc/adminhtml` folder you will be having `routes.xml`.
Example:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="lapisbard_storelocator" frontName="lapisbard_storelocator">
            <module name="Lapisbard_StoreLocator" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Here `frontName="lapisbard_storelocator"` is used to specify cotroller's frontname (`lapisbard_storelocator` is frontname here).

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1, menu configuration are located inside etc/adminhtml.xml but in Magento 2 menu configuration are located in etc/adminhtml/menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Ves_HelloWorld::brand" title="Ves Hello World" module="Ves_HelloWorld" sortOrder="30" resource="Ves_HelloWorld::brand"/>

        <add id="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_head_manage" title="Brand" module="Ves_HelloWorld" sortOrder="10" parent="Ves_HelloWorld::brand" resource="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_head_manage"/>

        <add id="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_new" title="Add New Brand" module="Ves_HelloWorld" sortOrder="10" parent="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_head_manage" action="veshelloworld/brand/new" resource="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_new"/>

        <add id="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_head_settings" title="Settings" module="Ves_HelloWorld" sortOrder="20" parent="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_head_manage" resource="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_manage"/>

        <add id="Ves_HelloWorld::configuration" title="Configuration" module="Ves_HelloWorld" sortOrder="6"
            parent="Ves_HelloWorld::brand_head_settings" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/vesbrand" resource="Ves_HelloWorld::configuration"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```