# Magento 2.X : How can I add a new tab in the admin panel?

Tags: magento2, backend, tabs, adminmenu

[image]

How can I add a new tab (Custom Menu section) in the left side bar of admin panel ?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101013/how-to-create-menu-and-its-controller-in-magento-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your custom extension you need to create file in following place.

```
Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml
```

Add following code into file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
  <menu>
    <add id="Vendor_Extension::yourresource" resource="Vendor_Extension::yourresource" module="Vendor_Extension" title="YOUR TITLE" sortOrder="20"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I add a new icon for the tab ?

Comment: Hope this will help you: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-how-to-create-custom-menu-in-admin-and-change-default-font-icon
Just want to mention if you planing upload the module to Magento store will be rejected. Magento policy is that you should find place in current menu for your module/extension, not to create new top level menu.

Comment: Hi @Nikola, Do you have a link which write about this Magento policy ? Thanks!

Comment: @MEIR http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ext-best-practices/admin/placement-and-design.html#icons-in-the-primary-navigation